# SQL Average based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| FirstName | LastName | SessionDate |  SessionTitle  | TotalDistance |
+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| Player    | Striker  |  05.08.2020 | Entire Session |          10.0 |
| Player    | Striker  |  05.08.2020 | 1v1            |           5.0 |
| Player    | Striker  |  06.08.2020 | Entire Session |          12.0 |
| Coach     | Defender |  06.08.2020 | Entire Session |           7.0 |
+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

What I need to do is to calculate the average for totalDistance, for each player individually. The average should only be calculated with values, where the SessionTitle is 'EntireSession' and only for the last 50 days for each row. So the expected result would look like this:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------+
| FirstName | LastName | SessionDate |  SessionTitle  | TotalDistance | average |
+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------+
| Player    | Striker  |  05.08.2020 | Entire Session |          10.0 |    10.0 |
| Player    | Striker  |  05.08.2020 | 1v1            |           5.0 |    10.0 |
| Player    | Striker  |  06.08.2020 | Entire Session |          12.0 |    11.0 |
| Coach     | Defender |  06.08.2020 | Entire Session |           7.0 |     7.0 |
+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------+
```

I tried something like this, but it is awfully slow, when more rows are added:

```
SELECT t1.FirstName, 
t1.LastName, 
t1.SessionDate, 
t1.SessionTitle, 
t1.TotalDistance, 
(SELECT (AVG(t2.TotalDistance) FROM myTable t2 WHERE t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName AND t2.SessionTitle = 'EntireSession' AND t2.SessionDate <= DATEADD(DAY,50,t1.SessionDate)) as average
FROM myTable t1
```

It is running on a Azure SQL-Server
How would the fastest way to get this done in a select statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your attempt

Answer (score 1):

We can use `AVG` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *, AVG(CASE WHEN SessionTitle = 'Entire Session' THEN TotalDistance END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY LastName, FirstName) AS average
FROM yourTable;
```

The strategy here is to compute the average total distance for each group of records belonging to each person.  We use a `CASE` expression which will return the `TotalDistance` when the session title happens to be `Entire Session`.  Otherwise, it would return `NULL` which by default is ignored by the `AVG` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction! One more question: How could I use the SessionDate in this query. I would like to only calculate the average with the values of the last 50 days in each row. Is it still possible with this approach

Comment: Yes it's possible to also filter by date by including a `WHERE` clause.  But, the exact syntax is highly database vendor specific.  So, you should edit your question and tell us your exact database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: I changed the requirements and the expected output table and also added the database type

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the "last 50 days" part is problematic in SQL Server, because it does not support `range` window frames with date/time intervals.  That precludes the simple use of. a window function (unless you have data on every day).

But, you can easily work around this using `apply`:

```
select t1.*, t2.average
from mytable t1 outer apply
     (select avg(t2.total_distance) as average
      from mytable t2
      where t2.FirstName = t1.FirstName and
            t2.LastName = t1.LastName and
            t2.SessionTitle = 'EntireSession' and
            t2.SessionDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -50, t1.SessionDate) and
            t2.SessionDate <= t1.SessionDate
     ) t2;
```

This is correctly phrased for what you want to do.  Otherwise, it is similar to the correlated subquery.

Next, you want an index to facilitate this calculation.  I would suggestion an index on `mytable(lastname, firstname, sessiontitle, sessiondate, total_distance)`.